# onkeyup event on HTML contenteditable element return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I'm trying to bind div element text value, based on another text of div contenteditable element using onkeyup event like below :

```
var input = document.getElementById('editor');

    input.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = input.text;
  }
```

and here's my markup :

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable>text here</div>

<div id="console"></div>
```

Or here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g3pv3xm0/)

But it's not working. I want any text we typing on that contenteditable div element is also changed directly on `<div id="console"></div>`

I'm sorry to give you confusing explanation, Hope you guys understand my question and my question is how can i solve this thing? or any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `input.text`. HTML Elements don't have a property named `text`, so when you get the value, it's `undefined`. Maybe you want `innerText`?

```js
var input = document.getElementById('editor');

input.onkeyup = function() {
  console.log(input.innerText)
  document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = input.innerText;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable>Type here</div>

<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: Aha yes this is what i looking for. thankyou sidney :) i just knowing about innerHtml and didn't know that innertext are exist LOL